# Unable to understand Fold in spark (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand Fold but the output I expected is different from what is the actual output and have difficulty understanding the terms in the documentation of fold.

What I understand about Fold is:

1. Fold result depends on number of partitions, because the zeroValue will be "applied" based on the number of partitions, Once for each partition then finally Once for reduction.
2. And number of partitions, numSlices, defaults to number of logical processors. I have a 5600x, so it defaults to 12, as it is 6 core, 12 threads.

With a simple example using Fold, I validated my understanding

```
sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5).fold(3, lambda x,y:x+y)

It will do like

=> op(3, 1) => 4

=> op(3, 2) => 5

=> op(3, 3) => 6

=> op(3, 4) => 7

=> op(3, 5) => 8

Then, reduce (4, 5, 6, 7, 8) => 30

Then op(3,30) => 33
```

But when I try validating the wordings of fold which is
``` The function ``op(t1, t2)`` is allowed to modify ``t1`` and return it as its result value to avoid object allocation; however, it should not modify ``t2``. ```

I tried the following snippet

```
class Fold_Class:
    def __init__(self, alpha=0):
        self.alpha = alpha

def fold_function(obj1, obj2):
    obj2.alpha *= 2
    return obj2

ls = sc.parallelize([Fold_Class(1), Fold_Class(2), Fold_Class(3)], 3)

folded_obj = ls.fold(Fold_Class(0), fold_function)
print(folded_obj.alpha)
```

Output of this snippet is 12, while I was expecting 24 because

```
=> op(Fold_Class(0), Fold_Class(1) => Fold_Class(2) # Writing like this for easy understanding

=> op(Fold_Class(0), Fold_Class(2) => Fold_Class(4)

=> op(Fold_Class(0), Fold_Class(3) => Fold_Class(6)

Then reduction should happen:

=> reduce(Fold_Class(2), Fold_Class(4)) => Fold_Class(8)

=> reduce(Fold_Class(8), Fold_Class(6)) => Fold_Class(12)

Then while reduction reduction is happening, last time zero_value is applied

op(Fold_Class(0), Fold_Class(12)) => Fold_Class(24)
```

So I have two questions:

1. My fold_function is modifying object2, which should not be allowed based on the documentation. I think I am understanding it wrong.
2. How is the fold function returning the value of 12?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to point 2, but point 1 I am still not clear and any help is appreciated.

So my issue was with not understanding how fold works.
My output for each partition is fine

Following source code from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L2019-L2023) :

```
    def fold(self: "RDD[T]", zeroValue: T, op: Callable[[T, T], T]) -> T:
        op = fail_on_stopiteration(op)
        def func(iterator: Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
        acc = zeroValue
        for obj in iterator:
            acc = op(acc, obj)
        yield acc

    # collecting result of mapPartitions here ensures that the copy of
    # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    # to the final reduce call
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)


> vals = [FC(2), FC(4), FC(6)] Now, reduce function will be  
> 
> reduce(op, vals, FC(0)]
> 
> Which will call reduce function as: op(op(FC(2), FC(4)), FC(6))
> Result of inner function is => op(FC(2), FC(4)) => FC(8)
> => op(FC(8), FC(6)) => FC(12)
```

So 12 is the output. I had set in my mind, that the final step was
op(zero_value, reduce(op, vals)) which was wrong